# GC overhead limit exceeded, but plenty of memory

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

My JBoss server had a weird issue: the exception thrown:

java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded

I looked for low memory conditions, but memory availability looked fine:

```
Heap Configuration:
   MinHeapFreeRatio = 40
   MaxHeapFreeRatio = 70
   MaxHeapSize      = 2147483648 (2048.0MB)
   NewSize          = 2228224 (2.125MB)
   MaxNewSize       = 4294901760 (4095.9375MB)
   OldSize          = 4194304 (4.0MB)
   NewRatio         = 2
   SurvivorRatio    = 8
   PermSize         = 16777216 (16.0MB)
   MaxPermSize      = 805306368 (768.0MB)

Heap Usage:
PS Young Generation
Eden Space:
   capacity = 176816128 (168.625MB)
   used     = 110937856 (105.798583984375MB)
   free     = 65878272 (62.826416015625MB)
   62.741932681616014% used
From Space:
   capacity = 38207488 (36.4375MB)
   used     = 27193584 (25.933822631835938MB)
   free     = 11013904 (10.503677368164062MB)
   71.17344118514151% used
To Space:
   capacity = 40960000 (39.0625MB)
   used     = 0 (0.0MB)
   free     = 40960000 (39.0625MB)
   0.0% used
PS Old Generation
   capacity = 1434451968 (1368.0MB)
   used     = 818386128 (780.4738311767578MB)
   free     = 616065840 (587.5261688232422MB)
   57.052180641575866% used
PS Perm Generation
   capacity = 113246208 (108.0MB)
   used     = 109507808 (104.43478393554688MB)
   free     = 3738400 (3.565216064453125MB)
   96.69887401439526% used
```

Has anyone encountered this GC exception before when there was seemingly plenty of memory?

Comment: Did you watch over time with jvisualvm in the JDK?

Comment: We don't have it configured to respond to jstatd/jmx connections.  We may start a periodic jmap -heap though

Comment: Jvisualvm can attach to a running JVM on the same machine.

Comment: Your Perm Gen is low and that is used when classes are loaded/unloaded when you (un)deploy a war/ear/etc. You can increase Perm Gen with `-XX:MaxPermSize=256m`. But if JBoss is leaking (see [here](https://community.jboss.org/message/804101) for example), or classes cannot be unloaded (e.g. background threads are never closed which keep references to old classes), it won't help much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What that error means is that the garbage collector is making an spectacular effort but doing very little actual work, another symptom of which is that your app gets very slow even when it's not executing any heavy task because it's spending most of its time running the GC, but don't just take my word for it, most JDKs include many tools like [jstat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/share/jstat.html) that you can use to monitor the behavior of your GC,

according to the [oracle docs](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/gc-tuning-6-140523.html#par_gc.oom):

> The parallel collector will throw an OutOfMemoryError if too much time is being spent in garbage collection: if more than 98% of the total time is spent in garbage collection and less than 2% of the heap is recovered, an OutOfMemoryError will be thrown. This feature is designed to prevent applications from running for an extended period of time while making little or no progress because the heap is too small

luckily they also say how you can get around it:

> If necessary, this feature can be disabled by adding the option -XX:-UseGCOverheadLimit to the command line

however, it will take away the error message but not the underlying cause, looking at your memory conditions doesn't look like you're running out of memory, so increasing the heap size is not gonna help either, quite likely the problem lies somewhere in your code, check the most memory intensive points of your app, look for places where you may be creating lots of objects and not letting go of them, and find a way to either not create so many or release as many as you can when you don't need them any more.

Comment: This answer has the most insight, because it addresses the memory conditions I included (lots of memory left).  The condition was reliably reproduced by an HTTP request that I'm fairly certain isn't very memory intensive, so I was hoping someone would bring up a HotSpot bug or something (it's 1.6.14 unfortunately).  I'll leave the question open a little while longer.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is as @Camilo Bermúdez says.

The "GC overhead limit" mechanism is a designed to kill your application if it is spending too much time running the garbage collector.

(The rationale is that if too much time is being spent garbage collecting, it is a sign that the JVM is "sick" ... probably terminally ... and the pragmatic solution is to "put it out of its misery".)

Now you *could* turn off the GC overhead limit mechanism, but it is a bad idea.  You risk getting into a worse situation.  The classic cause for the mechanism triggering is that you are running out of heap space (of some kind or another), and the GC is being run far too often.

A better strategy is to turn on GC logging, and (if indicated) either tune the GC or track down what is causing excessive memory demands.  In other words, track down and fix the root problem that is causing the GC overhead limit to trigger.

Answer (score 0):

Try if the following command line arguments help:

```
-Xms<size>        set initial Java heap size
-Xmx<size>        set maximum Java heap size
```